# How to derive selections from a series of numbers

Tags: database-theory

I am sure this question has been asked, but I was unable to search for it in a manner that would give me the solution. So I will present it here.

I seen this in another database years ago, and I want to implement it in one of my apps. It is perfect:

```
Pets
1. fish
2. dog
4. cat
8. monkey
16. mice
32. snakes
64. rock
```

If someone want a fish, cat, and a pet rock, that could be stored as 69.
I could never figure out how to extract the 69 to get the rock, cat and fish.

What is this method called, and what is the best way to reverse this?

Answer (score 0):

This is just the regular representation of a binary number, where the no. of bits represent the no. of types of that entity(pets in this case). You simply assign each bit position a unique type and then the bit value tells you whether that type is included or not. Binary representation is suitable cause you have 2 options for each type, which can be encoded in a binary number.

```
                     +------+--------+------+--------+-----+-----+------+
                     |  2^6 |   2^5  |  2^4 |   2^3  | 2^2 | 2^1 |  2^0 |
                     +======+========+======+========+=====+=====+======+
                     | rock | snakes | mice | monkey | cat | dog | fish |
                     +------+--------+------+--------+-----+-----+------+
                     |   1  |    0   |   0  |    0   |  1  |  0  |   1  |
                     +------+--------+------+--------+-----+-----+------+
                                 1000101(base2) => 69(base10)
```

In general if you have $n$ unique choices$(0.....n-1)$, then each unique unique selection can be represented as a decimal number by
$$N = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}b_{i}*2^{i}$$

where $b_{i}$ = bit at position $i$

If from this number you want to know what that selection was you'll need to check the bits individually which can be done as follows

```
input(N)
while (N > 0) do:
    bit = N % 2 (check this bit to know the selection of each type, this checks from LSB to MSB(from fish to rock in this case))
    N = N / 2
```

Comment: Thank! seems simple enough. I am working in php, so Ill scrawl up a code and post my version here. Is there a specific name for this process? I would like to change the title for something more meaningful for others that seek this out.

Comment: Nothing specific, but I guess this is an efficient way to store multiple binary columns, so you may use that.